# Android - How to disable horizontal scroll in google mapview?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using `google MapView` in my application and set the zoom level to 2 so that the world map with continent names are visible. Now I want to disable horizontal scrolling. Can any one share some idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just got an idea. Using `MotionEvent.AXIS_*` flags.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_AXIS_...) {
        // ...
    }
    return sper.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Look at AXIS_HSCROLL, AXIS_VSCROLL, AXIS_X, AXIS_Y, AXIS_Z: [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)